# React: onClick on Anchor element doesn't seem to work

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React for some time now and I have encountered a strange problem that I have troubles solving. It's pretty simple: onClick on my Anchor element doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```js
function Tabs(props) {
 return (
  <li className="nav-item">
     <a id="user-list-tab" className="nav-link tab-link" href="#" onClick={props.onTabClick}>{props.tabName}</a>
   </li>
 );
}

Tabs.propTypes = {
 onTabClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
 tabName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}



var TabsNav = React.createClass ({
 getInitialState: function() {
  return {
   tabs: [
   {name: "Users list", isActive: false},
   {name: "Create new user", isActive: false},
   ],
  }
 },
 showTabContent: function() {
  console.log("it works");
 },
 render: function() {
  return (
    <ul className="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center">
     {this.state.tabs.map(function(element, index) {
      return <Tabs tabName={element.name} className={element.isActive ? "nav-item active" : "nav-item"} onTabClick={this.showTabContent} />
     }.bind(this))}
    </ul>
  );
 }
})
```

When I click on the link nothing seems to happen ....

I would appreciate any help. It drives me crazy for quite some time now :)

Comment: What is the error in browser console? That `this` is not defined?

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/71236/). Your code is work... You just forgot key when use map, but it's not big deal.

Comment: I have no error in my console, I have binded "this" with .bind(this) so that's not the problem. The code is working apart from the fact that it's not logging "it works" to the console on the onClick event (and it should).

Comment: `Tabs` should also be a React Component, rather than a plain function.

Comment: I have turned it into a React Component and onClick is still not working :/

Comment: I'm seeing similar problems, when I look in the console it appears the onClick property is not added to the Anchor